# How to display PDF in a new tab instead of downloading?

Tags: pdf

I'd like to **open some external PDF files in a new tab instead of downloading them**.

Here you can see the problem : https://quantum-genomics.com/en/investors/annual-information/

[image]

Thx for your help ;)

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! You can't force how the user is seeing the PDF. That's a browser setting that cannot be overridden. The only thing you can do is providing a HTML alternative. Besides that, it's not WordPress related. :)